# Positioning Multiple UIImage's - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

In the app I'm building, a square image is imported, it is broken into 16 tiles, and those tiles are placed in a square on the screen, starting from the top. However, I'm adding an extra bar of info at the top above the tiles, so I need to move the set of tiles further down the screen. I've played around with the for loop and the coordinates that the code makes, but nothing is giving me the desired respect.

```
-(void) initPuzzle:(NSString *) imagePath{
UIImage *orgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];

if( orgImage == nil ){
    return; 
}

[self.tiles removeAllObjects];

tileWidth = orgImage.size.width/NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES;
tileHeight = orgImage.size.height/NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES;

blankPosition = CGPointMake( NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES-1, NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES-1 );

for( int x=0; x<NUM_HORIZONTAL_PIECES; x++ ){
    for( int y=0; y<NUM_VERTICAL_PIECES; y++ ){

        // *** The coordinates need to be altered - ?
        CGPoint orgPosition = CGPointMake(x,y); 

        if( blankPosition.x == orgPosition.x && blankPosition.y == orgPosition.y ){
            continue; 
        }

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tileWidth*x, tileHeight*y, 
                                  tileWidth, tileHeight );
        CGImageRef tileImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect( orgImage.CGImage, frame );
        UIImage *tileImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tileImageRef];

        CGRect tileFrame =  CGRectMake((tileWidth+TILE_SPACING)*x, (tileHeight+TILE_SPACING)*y, 
                                       tileWidth, tileHeight );

        tileImageView = [[Tile alloc] initWithImage:tileImage];
        tileImageView.frame = tileFrame;
        tileImageView.originalPosition = orgPosition;
        tileImageView.currentPosition = orgPosition;


        CGImageRelease( tileImageRef );

        [tiles addObject:tileImageView];

        // now add to view
        [self.view insertSubview:tileImageView atIndex:0];
    }
}

[self shuffle];
```

}

Comment: What is your question?  I see information, but not that you're asking anything.

Comment: How can I position the set of tiles further down the screen, say 100 pixels down or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
int topBarWidth = 100;     //100 based on the example in your comment
```

Then at the point in your code where you're setting the frames of each tile, add `topBarWidth` to whatever y value you were previously setting.

Comment: topBarHeight would be a better name and you'd use it like this:
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(tileWidth*x, (tileHeight*y) + topBarHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight );

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a subview just for your tiles and then reposition that instead.  If you then wanted to animate all the tiles moving up and down you'd only have to animate the tiles view, instead of recalculating the position of all the images.